# send html formated alert mail to admin in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

how to send HTML formated mail to admin.

not same as customer get. the admin get right mail content but that is not well formated so i want to add html css adnd other formating.

Comment: Do it the same way as the mail for customer is done. The mail for customer contains HTML template while for the admin emails only TXT emails are sent. Look at some logic that sends the mail to customer and try to use it also for following admin email. If You are stuck with some code, post it here to help You...

Answer (score 3):

OK, I'll send the answer here though I think You should do a more research and try something for Yourself. Usually a mail for customer is sent with this piece of code:

```
$mail = new Mail(); 
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
$mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
$mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
$mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
$mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');         
$mail->setTo($order_info['email']);
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender($order_info['store_name']);
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
// THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
$mail->setHtml($html);
$mail->setText(html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
// END OF IMPORTANT PART
$mail->send();
```

As You can see the two lines marked with a comment are setting the e-mail's HTML **and** TXT body, while with e-mails sent to admins only the TXT body is set:

```
    $mail = new Mail(); 
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
$mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
$mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
$mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
$mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');         
$mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender($order_info['store_name']);
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
// THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
$mail->setText(html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
// END OF IMPORTANT PART
$mail->send();
```

So here, in admin mail sending section, add this line:

```
$mail->setHtml($html);
```

before

```
$mail->setText(html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

and You should be done. Do not forget to change the `$subject` and `$text` variables with Yours...

Comment: You are asking usually before thinking or before doing your own research. That's not very vital here on SO :-)